# Underscore: losing reference to array of object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to sort an array using underscore inside a function. I am losing the reference to the parent array 'list' that is being passed to the 'orderData' function when using underscore 'sortBy'.

'console.log' after the function call doesn't give me sorted 'list' object. I need to be able to sort the array without losing the reference. Am I doing something wrong?

```
function orderData(data, testObj) {
  data = _.chain(data)
    .sortBy(function(item) {
      return new Date(item.dt).getTime();
    }).sortBy('text').value();
  testObj.x = "updated";
  console.log(data, testObj);
}

var list = [
{id: 3,dt: new Date('8/1/17'),text: 'a'}, 
{id: 1,dt: new Date('5/1/17'),text: 'a'}, 
{id: 4,dt: new Date('5/1/17'),text: 'b'},
{id: 2,dt: new Date('5/10/17'),text: 'a'}];

var testObj = {
  x: "Start"
};

//console.log(list,testObj);
orderData(list, testObj);
console.log(list, testObj);
```

Fiddle I was using to do this:
https://jsfiddle.net/9zo3qnej/1/

PS: I am newbie to underscore and also javascript.

Comment: And what exactly is the "parent object" in this context?

Comment: 'list' array from outside the function.

Comment: Yes, and you're modifying it inside the function? If you want to keep the array outside the function unchanged, you have to make a deep copy inside the function, and **return** that copy instead?

Comment: I am actually expecting the function to update 'list' array after the function call. I see that the 'testObj' is working as expected(textObj.x is being updated to 'updated'). But for some reason, the 'list' array is not being updated.

Comment: Oh okay, the documentation for `sortBy` states that it *"Returns a (stably) sorted copy"*, in other words, it already copies the array, so you're not working with the original. If you'd used the native `Array.sort` instead it would work, as it sorts "in place".

Comment: @adeneo ok thanks :) I will try that. It would have been good if I was able to use underscore to achieve this. Well, it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

When `data` is reassigned inside the function, it is only the local variable that is changed. The variable `list` itself cannot be altered via its passed parameter. (In more generic terms, the parameter is not passed 'by reference' )

The most direct solution without rewriting too much, is to have the function return the sorted array and reassign `list`:

```js
function orderData(data) {
  return _.chain(data)
    .sortBy(function(item) {
      return item.dt.getTime();
    }).sortBy('text').value();  
}

var list = [
{id: 3,dt: new Date('8/1/17'),text: 'a'}, 
{id: 1,dt: new Date('5/1/17'),text: 'a'}, 
{id: 4,dt: new Date('5/1/17'),text: 'b'},
{id: 2,dt: new Date('5/10/17'),text: 'a'}];

list = orderData(list);
console.log(list);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Also note that the 2nd `sortBy` is not a `then by` type of sort. That means, the last sort is prevalent and 'text' is the main sort order, then date. If it should be the other way around, the sorts should be reversed.

A second way would be using the js native `Array.sort` instead. This alters the order itself (which is not the same as assigning to the variable) and has the added benefit that you can compare both properties in one go.